# Button for adding an instance of formset in Django

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, formset

I want to create a button for dynamically adding and removing an instance of formset from the displayed page. It is my first experience with formset in Django and I do not know any JavaScript, so I would be grateful for any help. So, lines for the formset in my view look like this:

```
strategy_settings = formset_factory(StrategySettings, extra=1)
strategy_form = strategy_settings(request.POST)
```

I believe it is a matter of changing the value of an "extra" attribute, but I do not know how to achieve it in JavaScript.

here is my template:

```
{% extends "mainapp/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<form method="post" id="strategy-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ simulation_form.as_p }}
    {% for form in strategy_form %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {% endfor %}

    <button type="button">Add Strategy</button>
    <button type="button">Remove Strategy</button>

    <button type="submit" name="save">Submit</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Thanks to anyone in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `extra` value determines how many additional, empty forms are displayed initially.

As for the dynamic stuff, since you don't know any javascript (yet), I suggest you look into a 3rd party package that does what you want. For example here: https://djangopackages.org/search/?q=formset.